# Additional Offset X on Horizontally Centered Element

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, storyboard, offset

I have a SubView inside another View that has other elements inside it. I horizontally centered the middle element of SubView to SubView, but I need to give it an extra horizontal offset. Is there a way to be able to use both Horizontal Center and give extra offset?

Unfortunately, this isn't work:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()

        MyView.frame.origin.x += 50
   }
```

Comment: are you using autolayout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the constant value from 0 to 50 (or any value of choice) to give an offset to horizontal alignment.

See picture below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you were already heading into the right direction...

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let frame = MyView.frame
    frame.origin.x += 50
    MyView.frame = frame
}
```

if you are using autolayout though you have to modify constraints instead of modifying frames directly.